# mac ios : How can I find "SCM" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, version-control

very upset with the Xcode ,because of different versions. 
I use Xcode 4.3, and want to use SCM to manage project.
click "Xcode" -> Preferences,but not find it,below is a snapshot:

[image]

how can I find the "SCM"? 
thanks for you reply!

Comment: have you looked at this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/085-Save_and_Revert_Changes_to_Projects/manage_project_changes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH7-SW12?

Comment: xcode 4.3 will have "SCM" in the "Organizer".

Answer (score 1):

SCM: Source Control Management System. It's available in Xcode for Git and Subversion although Git is newer and used more. When you create a project in Xcode you will see a screen similar to this [Xcode Git Repository Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9lxi.png) Where you can add Git Source Control. Check Xcode Help for information on Subversion.

From there you can go to the Menu Option Source Control and put in the URL for the Github repository that you have set up for your Xcode project.